# Datetime in 24 hour format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

my type for date in the database is datetime  and format of the datetime i am getting is 2/21/2011 12:00:00 AM .how can i convert this into 24 hour format.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment which prompted this question, you need to show us the code you're using.

Comment: i am just trying to add the data to database by using database explorer in visual studio.if i enter 2/21/2011 in the datetime field there it is coming as 2/21/2011 12:00:00 AM and if i try to enter 2/21/2011 13:00:00 it is showing the error.

Comment: @saurabh: "It is coming" - how? In some *code* perhaps? Please *show us that code*.

Comment: my question is simple how can i get 24 hour format in datetime field.

Comment: how can i show you the code that i dont have!!! i am adding the data manually using databaase explorer in visual studio

Comment: @saurabh: Your question is probably simple to answer if you could actually provide the information you've been asked for...

Comment: @saurabh: If you don't have any code, how are you getting values? The database explorer in Visual Studio is pretty much irrelevant to what you'll get when you extract the data in code. In other words, without code there's really no question to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments I would suggest that you may have a mis-understanding.

After you enter datetime data into a database, it's not stored as text, it's not stored as AM/PM or 24 hour, it's its own type.  Only when an application converts it for display on screen does the difference materialise.  This is an artefact of the application, not the database.

Are you able to eloborate on why this is an issue to you?  How is the data being used?
- Are you going to be running any code?
- Are you copying it to Excell?
- Are you just basking in it's glory?

Comment: i want to subtract the two datetime field to get the hour difference between them . just by curiosity i have asked the question.

Comment: In which case it actually become irrelevant.  Both C# and SQL have ways of calculating that difference, before converting the datetime data type to a string for display :)

Answer (score 4):

Rather than changing the storage mechanism of the data in table, when you displaying the data, use the format you want and show it in your User Interface. Something like this:

```
DateTime.Parse(dateTime).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")
```

Comment: That's not really a good idea - a change to the database could break things. It's a much better idea to ask the database for the date/time *as* a date/time, and let the driver handle the conversion.

Comment: How is "DateTime.Parse" considered a change to the database?

Comment: @Jon You are absolutely right. I just answered the following question "how can i convert this into 24 hour format" and I assumed the conversion was to just display it in the UI. I totally agree with you on that.

Comment: @The Evil Greebo : He means that if you use this code, and then (seperately) database settings are changed, this code could break due to using a fixed time format.  (I believe)

Comment: @The Evil Greebo: Consider a change to the database settings (e.g. locale) such that it starts returning dd/MM/yyyy instead of MM/dd/yyyy. The code will suddenly stop working - or worse, give the wrong data. It's better to retrieve the DateTime *as* a DateTime from the database, and only deal in strings when you need to present the value to a user.